# Docker Desktop, Windows 10 - waiting for SSH to be available / certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Sharing a solution to this issue in case it's helpful to somebody, as the exact issue / fix doesn't seem to be covered by other threads with similar titles.

The symptom was that on attempting to create a new vm with `docker-machine create --driver hyperv testvm`, the process hung at:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(testvm) Copying F:\Virtual\Docker\cache\boot2docker.iso to 
F:\Virtual\Docker\machines\testvm\boot2docker.iso...
(testvm) Creating SSH key...
(testvm) Creating VM...
(testvm) Using switch "Docker External Switch"
(testvm) Creating VHD
(testvm) Starting VM...
(testvm) Waiting for host to start...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
```

This was with Windows 10 Pro, Hyper-V, and a fresh install of Docker Desktop Community 2.0.0.3 (although I suspect that Hyper-V is irrelevant to this issue).

When I `ctrl-c`'d out of the `create` command I could `docker-machine ls` and see that the VM was up, but was showing an error:

```
NAME     ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
testvm   -        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.5.61:2376           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.5.60:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

All attempts to `docker-machine ssh` to it failed similarly:

```
PS C:\> docker-machine ssh testvm
exit status 255
```

I tried using git bash as suggested in various threads elsewhere, but was seeing, eg:

```
$ docker-machine ssh testvm
Error: Cannot run SSH command: Host "testvm" is not running
```

(Likely some kind of configuration issue with my git bash install, but was unable to figure out what it was!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be some kind of compatibility issue with my installation of OpenSSH here:

```
PS C:\> get-command ssh

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ssh.exe                                            7.7.2.1    C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

This was producing debug output (when `docker-machine` was run with the `-debug` switch) along these lines:

```
(testvm) Calling .GetSSHPort
(testvm) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(testvm) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(testvm) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
&{[-F /dev/null -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none -o LogLevel=quiet -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null docker@192.168.5.61 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i F:\Virtual\Docker\machines\testvm\id_rsa -p 22] C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

Everything started to work when I used the `--native-ssh` switch which is [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/). I was then able to:

```
docker-machine --native-ssh regenerate-certs testvm
```

..to resolve the certificate issue, and:

```
PS C:\> docker-machine --native-ssh ssh testvm ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3301 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

..etc.

Probably better though to:

```
docker-machine rm -y testvm
docker-machine --native-ssh create --driver hyperv testvm
```

Everything was working for me without the switch at one point - my guess is that I didn't have OpenSSH installed at that time, and `docker-machine` was using its native version by default.